# Rotation of a single point in THREE.Point

Tags: three.js, glsl, webgl, shader

I have a Point inside a THREE.Points Three.js i would like to rotate the image of points individually. i saw a solution [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/1891).

i have tried it out but my output seems to weird.
[image of my result of rotating 0 degree to 45 degree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/piJI8.png)

Below is my Vertex Shader

```js
attribute vec3 color;
attribute float size;
attribute float rotation;

varying vec3 vColor;
varying float vRot;
void main()
{
  vColor = color;
  vRot = rotation;
  vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );   
  gl_PointSize = size * ( 300.0 / length( mvPosition.xyz ) );
  gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;
}
```

Below is my Fragment shader

```js
uniform sampler2D texture;
varying vec3 vColor;
varying float vRot; 
void main()
{
  vec4 outColor  = texture2D( texture, gl_PointCoord );
  if( outColor.a < 0.5  )
  {
    discard; 
  }  
  float mid = 0.5;
  vec2 rotated = vec2(cos(vRot) * (gl_PointCoord.x - mid) + sin(vRot) * (gl_PointCoord.y - mid) + mid, 
                      cos(vRot) * (gl_PointCoord.y - mid) - sin(vRot) * (gl_PointCoord.x - mid) + mid);
  vec4 rotatedTexture = texture2D( texture, rotated );    
  gl_FragColor   = outColor * vec4( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0 , 1.0 ) * rotatedTexture;
}
```

Please help me i am not sure what i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your formula looks incorrect.

The following is what I have come up with but I could be wrong. Try this:

```
rX = cos(angle) * x + sin(angle) * y;
rY = -sin(angle) * x + cos(angle) * y;
```

Based on rotating a 2D vector with a 2x2 matrix.

In your terms:

```
vec2 rotated = vec2(cos(vRot) * (gl_PointCoord.x-mid) + sin(vRot) * (gl_PointCoord.y-mid) + mid, 
                    -sin(vRot) * (gl_PointCoord.x-mid) + cos(vRot) * (gl_PointCoord.y-mid) + mid);
```